# Search a list of strings in pandas dataframe and add each search string to a new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a text column 'Description'
And I have a list of search strings as:

```
search = ['FR-001', 'FR-002, 'FR-003', 'FR-004']
```

I want to search the dataframe using strings in the search list. I used:

```
df.loc[df['Description'].str.contains('|'.join(search), na=False)]
```

I get the desired results such that all the rows are returned correctly.

How can I add each of successful search strings to the matching row in a new dataframe column 'FR'?

**Edit**

5 rows of Description column with Expected result column FR

[sample dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmsCJ.png)

Comment: I think can you add some 5 rows of sample data in `Description` and expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need [`findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

With sample data of @AndreyF:

```
search = ['FR-001', 'FR-002', 'FR-003', 'FR-004']
df['FR'] = df['Description'].str.findall('(' + '|'.join(search) + ')')
print (df)

                            Description                FR
0  AasfasfFR-001,asfasdfafsagsdg FR-002  [FR-001, FR-002]
1                 AasfasfFR-004, FR-002  [FR-004, FR-002]
2         AasfasfFR-02,asfasdfafsagsdg                 []
3  AasfasfFR-001,asfasdfafsagsdg FR-003  [FR-001, FR-003]
4  AasfasfFR-004,asfasdfafsagsdg FR-002  [FR-004, FR-002]
```

And if need filter out empty lists:

```
df = df[df['FR'].astype(bool)]
print (df)

                            Description                FR
0  AasfasfFR-001,asfasdfafsagsdg FR-002  [FR-001, FR-002]
1                 AasfasfFR-004, FR-002  [FR-004, FR-002]
3  AasfasfFR-001,asfasdfafsagsdg FR-003  [FR-001, FR-003]
4  AasfasfFR-004,asfasdfafsagsdg FR-002  [FR-004, FR-002]
```

Comment: I want to add the values such as FR-001, FR-002 etc in the new column FR and I am getting something like:
[, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: This one is better than my solution

Answer (score 1):

You can `apply` a function on each value and create there the string you want:

```
def find_values(to_search):
    ret_val = '('
    for val in search:
        if to_search.find(val) >= 0:
            ret_val += val + ','
    return ret_val[:-1] + ')' if len(ret_val) > 1 else ret_val + ')'

df['FR'] = df['Description'].apply(find_values)
```

For a dummy example of:

```
0  AasfasfFR-001,asfasdfafsagsdg FR-002
1                 AasfasfFR-004, FR-002
2         AasfasfFR-02,asfasdfafsagsdg 
3  AasfasfFR-001,asfasdfafsagsdg FR-003
4  AasfasfFR-004,asfasdfafsagsdg FR-002
```

The output will be:

```
                            Description               FR
0  AasfasfFR-001,asfasdfafsagsdg FR-002  (FR-001,FR-002)
1                 AasfasfFR-004, FR-002  (FR-002,FR-004)
2         AasfasfFR-02,asfasdfafsagsdg                ()
3  AasfasfFR-001,asfasdfafsagsdg FR-003  (FR-001,FR-003)
4  AasfasfFR-004,asfasdfafsagsdg FR-002  (FR-002,FR-004)
```